# verificar se varios campos estão criados na base de dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Foi adicionado em uma tabela mais 7 colunas, só que antes é preciso verificar se esta coluna está no banco senão não deve ser executado o script de criação das colunas.

Tem como em um única condição verificar se as colunas já foi criada no banco?
Segue o código:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM SYSCOLUMNS C 
               INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS T ON C.id = T.id 
               WHERE C.name = ('IdUserPreparo') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem' 
               AND ('dtSolicitacao') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem' 
               AND ('dtPreparo') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem'
               AND ('idUserCancel') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem'
               AND ('dtCancel') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem'
               AND ('IsCancelado') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem'
               AND ('obsCancel') 
               AND T.name = 'ComandaItem')
BEGIN
```

Este é o script de criação das colunas no banco:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ComandaItem ADD
    IdUserPreparo int NULL,
    dtSolicitacao datetime NULL,
    dtPreparo datetime NULL,
    idUserCancel int NULL,
    dtCancel datetime NULL,
    IsCancelado bit NULL,
    obsCancel varbinary(5000) NULL

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ComandaItem ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_ComandaItem_PessoaPreparo FOREIGN KEY
    (
    IdUserPreparo
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Pessoa
    (
    IDCadastro
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ComandaItem ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_ComandaItem_PessoaCancel FOREIGN KEY
    (
    idUserCancel
    ) REFERENCES dbo.Pessoa
    (
    IDCadastro
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  NO ACTION 

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ComandaItem SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

Comment: Porque quer fazer isso?

Comment: Por que , aqui a empresa a varias base de dado do cliente, e em cada base e feito alteração, algum pode ter os campo e outros não, sendo assim tenho que verificar na base dos cliente se este campo já estão criado, se não tiver os campo é criado o script cria senão não faz nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi que você precisa verificar se os sete campos existem, se for isso, algo bem simples seria o seguinte:

```
DECLARE @QTE_CAMPOS INT

SET @QTE_CAMPOS =
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        C.NAME   
    FROM 
        SYSCOLUMNS C 
        INNER JOIN SYSOBJECTS T 
        ON C.id = T.id
    WHERE
       T.xtype = 'U'                                                                                         
       AND T.NAME = 'NOME_TABELA'
       AND C.NAME IN ('CAMPO1','CAMPO2','CAMPO3','CAMPO4','CAMPO5','CAMPO6','CAMPO7')
) A
HAVING COUNT(*) = 7)

IF @QTE_CAMPOS = 7 
BEGIN
    Print 'NAO CRIA CAMPOS'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print 'CRIA CAMPOS'
END
```

Ou seja, o SQL acima retorna 7 se os 7 campos existirem e nada caso exista uma quantidade diferente.

Note, entretanto, que os 7 campos não podem existir. Caso contrário, você terá problemas ao criar.

Embora eu tenha dado essa resposta, creio que o mais defensivo é fazer um IF pra cada campo verificando se o mesmo existe, caso não exista, realiza a criação. São só 7 campos. Uma verificação pra cada um não vai custar muitas linhas de código.

Answer (score 2):

você pode usar o exemplo abaixo, ele verifica se as colunas existem no **in()** se não existirem ele roda o intervalo entre o **BEGIN** e o **END**..

Para identificar as colunas da tabela eu utilizei o **sys.columns**, ao utilizar o **sys.columns** preciso chamar o método **Object_ID()** setando a tabela(schema) para ele saber de onde buscar. Lembrando que [Obeject_ID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190328(v=SQL.120).aspx) , retorna o número de identificação do banco de dados do objeto de escopo de esquema.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
            WHERE Name in ('coluna1', 'coluna2') AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'suaTabela'))
BEGIN

    -- se as colunas que se encontram no in() não existirem ele irá executar o bloco que você colocar entre o BEGIN e o END

END
```

se você precisar executar se as colunas existirem basta retirar o **NOT** da primeira linha.

Comment: O Brunno, vc pode me explicar por que foi colocado este trecho de código Object_ID = Object_ID(N' ')

Comment: @krispim desculpa a demora! estava em horário de almoço rs .. atualizei a publicação a cima.

Comment: Obrigado  pela explicação Brunno